# Tag specific string replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string, tags

I have following function

```
function replacer(oldstring, newstring) {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(oldstring, newstring);
}
```

I want to be able to replace any text **if not inside** the following tag

```
<a id="word">some text</a>
```

or between < > characters.

Please can you show me if there is a way to skip when oldstring is inside **a** tag or between < > characters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good approach to replace the body's innerHTML, it result's in a re-rendering of the whole page, which may have undesired effects.

You may search the page for the string:

- IE: [range.findText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Others(except opera):[window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find)

If found any, determine , if the parent element-node of the range (or one of his ancestors too if needed) is the one to exclude. If not, replace the text.

Unfortunately none of both methods above works in opera.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do the trick:

```
function replacer(oldstring, newstring) {
    var regExp = new RegExp("(<[^<>]+>)" + oldstring + "(</[^<>]+>)", "g");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regExp, "$1" + newstring + "$2");
}
```

Comment: That's because I forgot to assign the new string to the body :)
It should work now ...